# How to launch a job in a shell which will persist even if the shell which launches it terminates

Tags: linux, shell, background-process

How do I lauch a job in a Linux shell, so that even if the shell which launches it terminates, this job will still persist?

More specifically, I am trying to run strace on a process. It runs perfectly if I do it in a terminal. However, I want to do it in a remote shell which will stop as soon as all the commands have been executed. `"strace -p pid &"` doesn't have any effect because when the shell stops, the background job also gets killed.

How should I do it?

`nohup` seems to be thing I am looking for. However, `ssh user@remote_machine script_name` doesn't seem to have any effect neither. In the script I have `"nohup strace -p pid"`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try nohup strace -p pid &

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Nohup` and `Screen` can be used to run a command even if the session is disconnected or the user logs out. I use them both, but “Screen” is better.

```
nohup ./<script_name> &
```

How to use screen?

creat a task:

```
$ screen -S task
```

Execute a command in the task window，if your task not finished, use

```
$ Ctrl+a+d
to save the task. It will show the following info:
[detached]
```

if your task has been finished, use “exit” to exit screen:

```
    $ exit

[screen is terminating]
```

You can use `screen -ls` to find any screen info:

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
10000.task (Detached)
```

Use “screen -r” to recover the task:

```
$ screen -r 10000
```

Comment: nohup seems to be thing I am looking for. However, ssh user@remote_machine <script_name> doesn't seem to have any effect neither. In the script I have "nohup strace -p pid"

Comment: you need to you '&' in end of nohup command like "nohup strace -p pid &' it will put process in background

Comment: There's also `disown`: `./script_name & disown -h`

Answer (score 2):

you could use "screen"!
Usage:

```
screen [Enter]
enter your command
[Ctrl] + [A] + [D(Detach)]
```

Your task continues running. If you want to go back to it just type in:

```
screen -r
```

or

```
screen -r -d (to detach old sessions)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of other answers, you may want to use the [batch(1)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_batch.htm) command (perhaps remotely thru `ssh`), like e.g.

```
  batch << ENDBATCH
    strace -p 1234 -o /tmp/trace.file
  ENDBATCH
```