# how to move to the end of line in screen linux

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

If `CTRL+A`+`a` is how you move to the beginning of a line in screen then what is the shortcut key to go to end of the line aside from the `End` key in screen.

I tried `CTRL+A` + `I` like in vim. no luck.

**Also OT: if you exit a shell will the session persist?**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

CTRL + E will take you to the end of the line.

Comment: wow. didnt figure that out. I thought all commands in screen starts with CTRL+A. thanks mate

Comment: No prob, take a look at this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/master-the-linux-bash-command-line-with-these-10-shortcuts/5827311

Comment: how about the offtopic question mate? give it a try.hehe

Comment: You can get some extra info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655114/how-to-launch-a-job-in-a-shell-which-will-persist-even-if-the-shell-which-launch

Comment: i cant understand you comment man, it will continue (persist)?

Answer (score 5):

SHIFT+HOME and SHIFT+END both work on my 104 key keyboard in screen and regular sessions.

OT: Closing the window does not kill your screen session, even when it's active.  Typing `exit` during the screen session will kill it.

Comment: For me (xubuntu 18.04) SHIFT+HOME and SHIFT+END do not "move" to the beginning/end of the line; they "select" from current cursor location to the beginning/end. HOME/END by themselves are what "move" to the beginning/end of the line without selecting.

Comment: I wanted to use this on Eclipse or DBeaver, UI based things, so this solution helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just press
CTRL + END button you will go to the bottom of the page directly...

If you want to go to beginning of the page just press CTRL + HOME

and want to go to end of line just press HOME or END